# linux read command - what is notused, discard?

Tags: bash

I've seen `notused` and `discard` used with the `read` command but I can't find where these two keywords are defined; they're not in the [docs for `read`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7214/393711

```
while read -t 0 notused; do
   read input
   echo "ignoring $input"
done
```

https://superuser.com/questions/276531/clear-stdin-before-reading

```
read -t 1 -n 10000 discard 
read -p "Give me some input: " input
```

Comment: `discard` is a variable name that's descriptive of a variable whose value is, well, *not used*. That said, it's a fairly uncommon choice; I more frequently see `_` used for the purpose.

Comment: @Charles `-t` is "timeout". You're thinking of `-u` for setting the FD. I think `-t 0` is being used here to soak up anything fed into stdin before the loop happens.

Comment: @wjandrea, quite right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**These are not keywords at all**; they're just variable names. They fit into the syntax in the position `[name ...]`, wherein any arbitrary names (including names that intentionally imply that data should not be used!) can be given for the content that is read.